# Python multiprocessing: how to constrain the amount of memory used by a Pool?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

When working on a script, you may wish to use all available cores for best performance.

There are cases however, when each sub-process uses a lot of memory, where it may be useful to set a memory threshold for the pool to prevent each task in the tool from running out of memory or cause the system to swap.

Is there a way of setting a memory threshold so new processes are only started when the combined memory use of all other tasks in the pool is under a threshold? (or something roughly equivalent).

Comment: if you are talking about `multiprocessing.Pool` objects, there is nothing built in that does that. but you could try to hack something together

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `resource` module with the `initializer` callback to control how much memory the Python interpreter can use in each worker.

```
import resource
from multiprocessing import Pool

MAX_MEM = 1024

def initializer(limit):
    """Set maximum amount of memory each worker process can allocate."""
    soft, hard = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS)
    resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS, (limit, hard))

def function():
    """This function tries to allocate 1Mb worth of string."""
    string = ''

    for _ in range(1024):
        string += 1024 * 'A'

pool = Pool(initializer=initializer, initargs=(MAX_MEM,))
pool.apply(function)
```